# Firebase Tools installation gets stuck often

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to learn firebase functions and so, i have installed `node.js` but when i run `npm install -g firebase-tools` command it completes upto approx. 50% process and then stuck there. when i stop this and re-run this command it completes installation with some warnings.

After that i have tried to install `firebase functions` tool in this and it also stops in between. i am including screenshot of it as below.

[image]

So, please anyone can help me in deal with this problem? i am running windows 10 and using latest recommended version of `node.js`.

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you!.

## UPDATE

I have cancelled this process after waiting for approx. 8-10 minutes and tried again to install firebase functions and this time it gets installed. so, i want to know what could be the problem? because same thing was happened while firebase tools installation. If anyone have idea then please let me know.

Comment: Did you try deleting everything from the location where you ran `firebase init` and start over?

Comment: No, i didn't tried to delete anything

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue while installing firebase tools. You can do the following: 
type this command on the cmd
**npm config set strict-ssl false**
Then try:
**npm install -g firebase-tools**
This may solve your problem!